# React native app cannot run after upgrade

Tags: android, react-native

Hi guys been trying to run my react native project but have failed. Initially, i could deploy it very well on my device while using linux, but when i ran it on windows now it throws an. Can any one help me out, here is the screen shot on my nodejs console.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

You see the list of actions to take to fix the issue? I would do each of them.

Comment: are you using expo? If yes, check this out https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md and compare it to your package.json

Comment: Am just  running it on my device because i created it using react-native init hence it's built with native code . But Expo is installed on the device.

Comment: forget my previous comment so. that was just for using expo. You are not using expo.